# App doesn't run after downgrading SDK from 29 to SDK 28

Tags: android

So I need to change my target SDK from 29 to 28 because I need my app to be working on Android version 5.1
It does run like charm on Android 7 to 10 while use target SDK 29,
when I changed target SDK to SDK 28, it can't even compile.

My Gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

I did several changes like change the libraries to older version but I got more error, so I reverted the change,
here's the error I got, I wonder how could I solve this error

[image]

Comment: Why did you change the `compileSdkVersion` at all? That should always be the latest version (and doesn't affect runtime behavior).

Comment: @ianhanniballake I need my app to work on Android 5 or higher, I read some random articles that I should downgrade my `compileSdkVersion`?

Comment: I think you've been misled. There's nothing `compileSdkVersion` does that would prefer your app working on older versions of Android.

Comment: Ahh got it,  I'll try another way, many thanks!

Comment: You should change the `minSdkVersion` instead, Although from your code I see already that your `minSdkVersion` is just where it should be; 21